# How to determine whether a system of linear inequalities has a positive solution or not?

Tags: linear-programming, decision-problems

> How to determine whether a system of linear inequalities has a *positive* solution or not?

Is there any poly-time algorithm to do this? Or the best algorithms known are no less complex than algorithms for solving set of linear inequalities?

Comment: Question posted at mathoverflow and was closed. Don't remember the link.

Comment: Note that search for positive solutions can be written as another general linear inequality because $x_i>0$ is just a linear inequality, so you can add it to your system and you still have a system of linear equalities.

Comment: @Benjamin: Two versions at MO were posted: [This one](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85731/how-to-determine-whether-a-system-of-linear-inequalities-has-a-positive-solution) and [this one](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85669/how-to-determine-whether-a-system-of-linear-inequalities-has-a-solution-or-not). They were both closed there. But, they're clearly on-topic here.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is known as Linear Programming (if you change positive to non-negative). Usually linear programming is thought of as an optimization problem, but in fact the optimization problem is equivalent to *feasibility*, which is exactly what you're asking: whether a system of inequalities has any solution.

If you really want to ask whether there's a positive solution, then what you can do is take your system of inequalities $Ax \geq b$ and add the constraint $x_i \geq m$, maximizing over $m$. If the maximum is $m > 0$, then there is a strictly positive solution, otherwise there isn't.