# Determine feasibility of a linear system of inequalities

Tags: reference-request, linear-programming, decision-problems

This sounds like a famous and straightforward question, but I do not know how exactly to solve it, although I have some rather half-baked ideas.  I have already looked at these two answers, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/99320) and [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/968), which are nice, but do not exactly answer my question.

I have a linear system of inequalities that I can *probably* rearrange to $ \mathbf{Ax} > \mathbf{b} $, and I am only interested to know the feasibility of the system, that is, yes or no.

In my particular problem, $ \mathbf{A} $ is a square matrix of reals ($ 8 \times 8 $).  And there are no sign constraints on the elements of the vector $ \mathbf{x} $.  And $ \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{0} $.

I am interested to know how exactly I need to reformulate the problem to be able to feed it to a Linear Programming solver to check for the feasibility of the system.

The issue with LP solvers is that they need an objective function.  I know from the answers linked above that this feasibility problem can be converted to an optimization problem by replacing, for instance, the first element of $ \mathbf{b} $ (which is 0) by $ b_1 $, and then maximizing $ b_1 $ under the same constraints.

Now I have an objective function.  If a nonnegative $ b_1$ was found, that is, $ b_1 \geqslant  0 $, then the system is feasible.  Otherwise, it is not.

Any help, comment, or reference work about my analysis would be appreciated.  Look at [my specific problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvMS0.jpg).

Comment: You can always use the zero objective function.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I set objective function to zero and the solver gives me the trivial solution zero which is not even correct. because half of my constraints are *strictly* less than zero.  (I used the R package lpSolve (originally lp_solve))

Comment: You cannot express strict constraints using linear programming.

Comment: The solver found out that your program were feasible. It did its job.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I understand that you are saying theoretically strict constraints are not allowed.  But the software allows for strict signs, < and >, in its documentation and throws no error when I use them.  Yet again, the zero solution does not satisfy half of my constraints that are strictly less than zero (see problem picture at the bottom of question).

Comment: How can I be sure that the program is feasible when the solution given by the software does not satisfy some of the constraints.

Comment: An LP solver returns either an optimal solution, states that the objective function is unbounded, or that the program is infeasible. These are mutually exclusive.

Comment: In order to fake a strict constraint, replace $x > 0$ by $x \geq \epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Farkas' Lemma gives a criterion for the feasibility of the system $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{x} \geq \mathbf{0}$, which is an equivalent problem to yours by adding slack variables. It states that such a solution exists if and only if the linear program
\begin{align*}
min. \, &\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{y} \\
subject\,to\, &A^T\mathbf{y} \geq \mathbf{0}\end{align*}
has a nonnegative optimum. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma.

Comment: I think this worked.  To transform my system of inequalities to the equivalent system of equations $ A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}, \ \mathbf{x} \geqslant \mathbf{0} $, I needed to use *slack* and *excess* variables, fake strict constraints using a small $ \epsilon $, and substitute all unconstrained in sign variables $ \alpha_i $ with $ \alpha_i = \alpha'_i - \alpha''_i, \ \alpha'_i, \alpha''_i \geqslant 0 $.  Thanks to Joshua and @YuvalFilmus.